# Python Pandas: Group a column together by duplicates and join strings within a corresponding column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby, data-science

I'm looking to group or (groupby) the PO Header Ids and then concatenate the strings (XML) for all the rows where the PO Header IDs are the same. I've stumbled upon a few code samples but have been getting some errors.

Ultimately, the column Final_XML is what I am looking to achieve.

```
PO Header ID   XML   Combined_XML
123           <test1> 
123           <test2> 
456           <test3> 
567           <test4> 
567           <test5> 
567           <test6> 

Desired output
PO Header ID   Combined_XML
123            <test1><test2>
456            <test3>
567            <test4><test5><test6>
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    combineXML = df.groupby(['PO Header Id']).agg(['Combined_XML']).apply(list).reset_index()
    print(combineXML)
    Throws error: KeyError: 'PO Header Id' There are no spaces in the column name so I am not sure 
    why it is not working
    df = df.groupby(['PO Header Id','XML'])['Combined_XML'].apply(''.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: Let me know whether my answer works for you, or any fine-tuning required ?   Thanks!

Comment: Hi Scott, please feedback whether my answer works for you, or any fine-tuning required ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try in this way
`df.groupby(['PO Header ID'])['XML'].apply(''.join).reset_index()`

Comment: File ".\Prepare-Data.py", line 58, in groupPOsAndMergeXML
    combineXML = df.groupby(['PO Header ID'])['XML'].apply(''.join).reset_index()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7636, in groupby
    dropna=dropna,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 896, in __init__
    dropna=self.dropna,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 860, in get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'PO Header ID'

Comment: @Scott  Seems like the error was owing to your column label is actually `'PO Header Id'` rather than `'PO Header ID'` (`Id` rather than `ID`)  that you posted as sample data.  After fixing this, this solution should work except the column label is not `Combined_XML`  as in your expected result.  If you want exact column label, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.GroupBy.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) as follows:

```
combineXML = df.groupby('PO Header ID', as_index=False).agg(Combined_XML=('XML', ''.join))
```

or use the following if your column name is actually `PO Header Id`:

```
combineXML = df.groupby('PO Header Id', as_index=False).agg(Combined_XML=('XML', ''.join))
```

Result:

```
print(combineXML)


   PO Header ID           Combined_XML
0           123         <test1><test2>
1           456                <test3>
2           567  <test4><test5><test6>
```